# pojo declaraion outside forloop

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I have an one scenario in my application,

I have to add 20 POJO objects into ArrayList. In that case I have a method like below.

```
 public void methodname() {

ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();    
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
     User userobj = new User();
     userobj.setName("xxx");
     userobj.setFirstName("xxx");
     userobj.setLastName("yyy");
arr.add(userobj);
    } // end of for loop

    }
```

one of friends suggest to change the UserObj declaration outside for loop.

```
  public void methodname() {
    User userobj = new User();
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();    
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
     userobj.setName("xxx");
     userobj.setFirstName("xxx");
     userobj.setLastName("yyy");
arr.add(userobj);
    } // end of for loop

    }
```

in the first approach, I created the userobj inside the for loop, so when next iteration comes previous userobj will be eligible for garbage collector..

I would like to know is there any significant performance will improve on the second approach?

Comment: *"one of friends suggest"* this is not your friend since she forced you to wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know is there any significant performance will improve on the second approach?

Did you *experience*  a difference?

When programming you should focus on *correctness* and *readability* of your code.

Do not even Think about performance unless you have an actual performance problem and you have **proven by profiling** that a certain construct is the cause.

The ultimate universal performance tip is:

> The fastest way to do something is not doing it.

So focus on good algorithms that avoid unneeded/hidden loops rather than on syntax variants that *may* improve performance.

Comment: while absolutely correct, this fails to answer the question directly. You fail to explain the difference between the two ways, and how they are not even related to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Both the ways, will produce different results.

> **In the First one**, you create **20 separate Objects**, and add them to the List. Thus, **changes on one of them, won't affect the others**.
>
> **The Second,** however, has the **same object**. Thus, **changes on one will reflect the others**. Actually, at the end, the **attributes of the all the Objects would be the same**, i.e, equal to the **last added Object**
>
> Performance-wise, you can't say. The Objects would only be eligible for garbage collection, when **there are no references pointing to them**. However, as both the ways perform separate functions, you can't compare them.

Alas, your Friend is wrong. The First way is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the first and the second approach is that in the first case you create 20 different `User` in memory which are assigned to the array.

In the second case you create only one `User` in memory but change its properties 20 times and assign the same `User` to all 20 positions of the array.

Regardless of the first scenario or the second, your `User` instances created are eligible for garbage collection only when the array itself is eligible for garbage collection, expect you remove the association with the array.

Garbage collection takes place only for an instance if there is no other instance referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be inside the loop, otherwise you are only adding the SAME user 20 times !

Answer (score 0):

On the second approach you will have only one last object in the list

Answer (score 0):

I think that the right way is:
 - declaration outside
 - instantiation inside

```
public void methodname() {
  ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
  User userobj; 
  for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
     userobj = new User();
     userobj.setName("xxx");
     userobj.setFirstName("xxx");
     userobj.setLastName("yyy");
     arr.add(userobj);
  } // end of for loop

}
```